# remove mas370 tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

there are currently 6 [mas370](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mas370) questions (of which 2 are closed). However each of these could be asked without referencing the missing plane.

I suggest removing the tag from these and removing the tag entirely

Answer (score 9):

I think that we should have a generic [accident-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident-investigation) tag for all questions related to investigations.  I can't see having enough questions about each specific accident to warrant having their own tags.

Comment: If this specific tag continues to re-appear (due to people finding the site looking for information about that flight) - let me know and I'll put it in the tag blacklist. Not being able to add that tag should be a strong clue that we probably won't be able to help you any more than CNN when it comes to the fate of that particular plane.

Comment: @TimPost I think that the only reason that we had six was because one person added them to all of the questions.  I doubt that this will be a major issue,  but if it keeps coming up we will let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since none of these questions are really specific to the Malaysian Airlines incident I've removed the tag from them (they, and [other questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=370) referencing this incident could probably stand further cleanup to make them more generically applicable.

---

As a general rule I don't think accident tags are ipso facto a bad thing, but the question needs to be intimately tied to the accident (and it'd be hard to have such a question where the answer isn't "Have you read the Wikipedia article and the NTSB Probable Cause report?")

Answer (score 1):

The reason I choose to add this tag is to be able to group all the questions related to this accident. For someone new to this site looking for info related to this accident it's easier when all questions are tagged accordingly. For one thing it avoids duplicates.

Secondly it allows to filter on it (e.g. I don't want to be distracted by all the MAS370 questions all the time)

Thirdly, when more information becomes available in the future (e.g. interim / final accident reports) it is helpful to have these questions tagged so it becomes easier to correct / supplement earlier answers.

Comment: I could definitely see a [tag:MAS370] tag for stuff that's specifically related to MAS370 - I just don't see much that is yet except maybe [the one about bulk-processing satellite data](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/lost-plane-over-ocean-bulk-processing-of-satellite-data) which I could see putting the tag back on. Instead it seems like we have a pretty good general question about ACARS, one about transponders & tracking, etc.

Comment: @voretaq7 Even that question could apply to other situations/accidents.  Other than one "what happened to..." question about each accident (which would hardly require its own tag), any question about aircraft systems, search and rescue, pilot actions, atc procedures, etc. can really be a generic question which can apply to more than one specific accident/incident/aircraft.